# SQL SERVER : select the latest comment using the max date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like so:

Id, Comment, LastUpdatedDate

I'm tyring to select the latest comment for that id. The table can have many comments on that id with different dates but I'm trying to get the latest date out of there. I've tried the following with no success:

```
SELECT tt.*
    FROM tagtestresultcomment tt
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT tag_id, MAX(last_update) AS MaxDateTime
FROM tagtestresultcomment
GROUP BY tag_id
) groupedtt ON tt.tag_id = groupedtt.tag_id AND tt.last_update = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
order by tag_id
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query code is too redundant. first

```
 tt.tag_id = groupedtt.tag_id AND tt.last_update = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

it's enough just

```
 tt.tag_id = groupedtt.tag_id
```

and second, it's enough just

```
SELECT [desired field list extcept last_update and ], 
  tag_id, 
  MAX(last_update) AS MaxDateTime
FROM 
  tagtestresultcomment
group by 
 tag_id, [desired field list extcept last_update and tag_id]
```

at all to achieve your objective

Comment: If you have tag_id in the select you have to include it in the group by clause

Comment: You can have max date for the id. But what about the comments? In this case you need a nested query or something similar, can't avoid it

Comment: the author did not mention that this query should be netsted anywhere

Comment: He say's "I'm tyring to select the latest comment for that id", so nesting is needed, else you have to group by with the comments column, and the result will be wrong.

Comment: look like you're right and i'm wrong) the question is composed not so clear, you may downvote me.

Comment: I consider downvoting "bad" for someone spent his time to help someone else. NO downvoting!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want only the latest comment *for each* tag_id? In which case, here is one approach you can use from SQL 2005 and on:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tag_id ORDER BY last_update DESC) AS RowNo
FROM TagTestResultComment 
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNo = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Select * from tagtestresultcomment where last_update in 
(select max(last_update) from tagtestresultcomment group by tag_id)
```

Comment: But if 2 comments for different tag_id's have the same last_update value, then both will be returned - even if for one of those comments, it's not actually the latest comment.

Comment: that will be in case that he stores only date without time

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this:

```
declare @tagtestresultcomment table
(
id int
, comment varchar(50)
,LastUpdatedDate datetime
)

--==== Populate table

insert into @tagtestresultcomment(id,comment,LastUpdatedDate)

select 1,'My name is Arthur','2011-06-09 00:00:00' union all

select 2,'My name is DW','2011-06-19 00:00:00' union all

select 2,'Arthur is my brother','2011-06-21 00:00:00' union all

select 1,'I have a sister named DW','2011-06-21 00:00:00' union all

select 3,'I am Muffy','2011-06-14 00:00:00' union all

select 3,'I like sports','2011-06-14 00:00:00'

-- SELECT stmt

select * from @tagtestresultcomment t 
join
(
select id, MAX(lastupdateddate) as LastUpdatedDate from @tagtestresultcomment group by id
) m

on t.id = m.id 

and t.LastUpdatedDate = m.LastUpdatedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The "MAX" group function wasn't working for me, so I used a sub-query. I had trouble wrapping my head around your single table example, so I'm using a common parent-child 1-to-many relationship with a blog and comment tables as an example.

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  b.content,
  c.id,
  c.blog_id,
  c.content,
  c.last_update
FROM blog b
INNER JOIN blog_comment c
ON b.id = c.blog_id AND c.id = (
  SELECT TOP 1 id FROM blog_comment WHERE blog_id = b.id ORDER BY last_update DESC
)
```

The query takes a hit on my sub-query, as it will call that "SELECT TOP 1" query for each record in the blog table. I'd like to hear of a faster, more efficient example if possible.